# When I pass in nothing as a parameter I am getting an error in my expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

```
=String.Format("{0:C}", IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!Pricing.Value), 0, IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!CPPrice.Value), IIf(Parameters!ControlPanel.Value.ToString().Contains("D"), CInt(Parameters!Pricing.Value * 2), CInt(Parameters!Pricing.Value)), CInt(Parameters!Pricing.Value))) 
+ IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!RMPrice.Value), 0, CInt(Parameters!RMPrice.Value)) 
+ IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!CPPrice.Value), 0, CInt(Parameters!CPPrice.Value))
+ IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!CKPrice.Value), 0, CInt(Parameters!CKPrice.Value)) 
+ IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!FPrice.Value), 0, CInt(Parameters!FPrice.Value)) 
+ IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!GRPrice.Value), 0, IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!CPPrice.Value), CInt(Parameters!GRPrice.Value), IIf(Parameters!ControlPanel.Value.ToString().Contains("D"), CInt(Parameters!GRPrice.Value * 2), CInt(Parameters!GRPrice.Value)))))
```

This is an expression I am trying to use in my report.  It is looking at several prices being passed in and totaling those prices.

If a control panel `Parameters!ControlPanel.Value` contains a D, then double the price of `Parameters!Pricing.Value` and `Parameters!GRPrice.Value` if is nothing.

Everything seems to work fine when there is a price / value passed in for `Parameters!ControlPanel.Value` and `Parameters!CPPrice.Value`, but if nothing is passed in, I get an #Error result.

Update: This is also giving me an error:

```
=String.Format("{0:C}", IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!Pricing.Value), 0, IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!ControlPanel.Value), CInt(Parameters!Pricing.Value), IIf(Parameters!ControlPanel.Value.ToString().Contains("D"), CInt(Parameters!Pricing.Value * 2), CInt(Parameters!Pricing.Value))))
+ IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!RMPrice.Value), 0, CInt(Parameters!RMPrice.Value)) 
+ IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!CPPrice.Value), 0, CInt(Parameters!CPPrice.Value))
+ IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!CKPrice.Value), 0, CInt(Parameters!CKPrice.Value)) 
+ IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!FPrice.Value), 0, CInt(Parameters!FPrice.Value)) 
+ IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!GRPrice.Value), 0, IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!ControlPanel.Value), CInt(Parameters!GRPrice.Value), IIf(Parameters!ControlPanel.Value.ToString().Contains("D"), CInt(Parameters!GRPrice.Value * 2), CInt(Parameters!GRPrice.Value)))))
```

Comment: I see  you would need to add IsNothing before using it's value like,
`IIf(Parameters!ControlPanel.Value.ToString().Contains("D"), CInt(Parameters!Pricing.Value * 2), CInt(Parameters!Pricing.Value))`you should first check `Parameters!ControlPanel.Value` for is nothing

Comment: `IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!Pricing.Value), 0, IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!ControlPanel.Value), CInt(Parameters!Pricing.Value), IIf(Parameters!ControlPanel.Value.ToString().Contains("D"), CInt(Parameters!Pricing.Value * 2), CInt(Parameters!Pricing.Value))))`  I have tried this on the first part and I still am getting an error.